# Umbraco 7 error, when trying to render model through partial View

Tags: .net, partial, umbraco7

I'm getting the following error when trying to render a form from a custom model in Umbraco 7.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel', but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type 'LeaveRequestStart'.

I'm using the documentation from [Umbraco](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/templating/mvc/forms) here to generate a form using a model, surface controller and partial view but keep receiving the above error.

here is the Model

```
public class LeaveRequestStart { 

    [Required]
        public String LeaveStart { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String LeaveEnd { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LeaveType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Boolean HalfDayStart { get; set; }
        public Boolean HalfDayEnd { get; set; }



    }
```

Here is the partial

```
@model LeaveRequestStart    
    @using UmbracoWithMvc.Controllers

    @using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("CreateLeave", "LeaveRequestSurface"))
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(x => Model)
        <input type="submit" />
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, i have also tried to derive my LeaveRequestStart model from RenderModel but still no love.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you here that the default rendermodel is being passed into the partial view, and it requires an instantiated LeaveRequestStart model to work / render.

In the view you're using to call this partial, how is the partial being called?
In the example tutorial it shows as this;

```
@Html.Partial("BlogCommentForm")
```

How does it look within your view? It should look something like this;

```
@Html.Partial("PartialView", Model.LeaveRequestStart );
```

Comment: Thanks your logic was correct, after passing it in as @Html.Partial("LeaveForm", new LeaveRequestStart()) it worked